# Which function does かって after a negative verb have?

Tags: grammar

I stumbled upon this sentence on the first episode of Midnight Diner:

> 向こうの社長にもう少し踊ってくれないかって頼まれたけど

It gets translated to something like:

> The president over there asked me to dance a little more.

If I were to write the “asked me to dance” part myself I would go for something like:

> 踊ってくれて頼まれた

I have done some google searches but I had no luck so far finding a ないかって grammar pattern. Is the かって supposed to be actually 勝って. That would still make no sense in my somehow intermediate Nihongo mind but it would get kind of closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't parsing it correctly.  It goes like this:

> (向こうの社長に(もう少し踊ってくれないか)) って頼まれたけど

The か is the question marker, and it's simply part of the question 「もう少し踊ってくれないか」 ("Won't you dance a little more?" as a Japanese passive request).

The って is the quotation marker—the informal of と.  So with the 頼まれた

> I was asked "Won't you dance a little more?" by my/that 社長 over there